# using csplit to split a file based on a regular expression to multiple files

Tags: csplit

I have a text file that has the contents of the example below, and I would like to split the file to multiple files.

```
[TXT]   /path/to/[TXT]
[BAT]   /path/to/[BAT]
[TXT]   /path/to/blah/[TXT]
[BAT]   /path/to/blah/[BAT]
```

So I have figured out I can use `csplit` to at least partially do what I wanted to achieve.

`csplit -f 'paths-' -b '%04d.txt' 'path/to/filelist.txt' '/^\[(.*)]\t/' '{*}'`

However this splits to `paths-0000.txt`.

I was hoping for something more like `paths-txt.txt` and `paths-bat.txt`.

Is there anyway I can get the regex match into the prefix match at all?

I did try things like `-f 'paths-$1.txt'` and `-f 'paths-\1.txt'`.

But neither of those did what I was hoping for them to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using csplit is the wrong tool for this job.

I used awk instead to achieved what I was trying to do.

`awk -F"\t" '{print > $1".txt"}' /path/to/filelist.txt`

You can if you wish limit it so only certain parts of the file are kept after the split, but I needed/wanted everything.

`awk -F"\t" '{print $2 > $1".txt"}' /path/to/filelist.txt`